# Can I render views to layout regions before showing that layout in a parent region using Marionette?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm using Backbone.Marionette to create nested Layouts and regions. I'm trying to build up a nested view structure before showing it in the DOM. The idea is to avoid the number of paints/reflows in the browser caused by going the traditional route of showing a Region, then showing a layout of regions, then showing itemViews and collection views in those layout regions. Instead, I'd like be able to work backwards, doing all of this work in JavaScript only to show the container region once the nested views are rendered. Am I crazy for thinking this should be possible?

Here's a dumbed down hierarchy.

```
- mainRegion (region)
  - lesson (layout containing regions)
    - contentRegion (region)
      - vocabulary (itemView)
```

The mainRegion el is a part of index.html.

**Lesson Layout**

```
Layout = Marionette.Layout.extend({
    template: tpl_layout,
    regions: {
        contentRegion: '.content-region'
    }
});
```

**Vocabulary ItemView**

```
Word = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: tpl_word
});
```

Some logic I was thinking should work.

```
layout = new Layout();

// Once the layout is rendered, I should be able to work with it,
// adding views to it before actually "show"ing in the DOM.
layout.render();

var wordView = new Word();
layout.contentRegion.show( wordView );
console.log(wordView.$el.html()); // Will output correct html to console

mainRegion.show(layout); // Will show layout in DOM, but will empty regions
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to call render() on Layouts. Just use mainRegion.show(layout); remove layout.render()

after adding layout to mainRegion show the according view in the layout's region.

Answer (score -1):

The proper way to populate your `Views` with the `Model` data and the selected `Template` is to call `render()` on the views.

If you want to keep your views from being displayed in the DOM you could you simply hide them using css, eg:

```
.mainRegion {
  display: none
}
```

A controller could listen to an event emitted by the child view and turn the visibility of your views.

There are many different ways to achieve what you are looking for, I would strongly advice you to keep your views loosely decoupled. The controllers are a fundamental to make your app "dance" without getting a mess.

In case you are waiting for async data to be fetched before you render your views take look into this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497763/render-a-marionette-region-after-model-has-been-fetched).

Comment: Sorry, this isn't what I was looking for. So far, I've been getting some excellent support from some of the Marionette contributors. https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/pull/1018

Comment: @Jarrod that's great! The PR looks nice also, by far better that the answer I provided. Maybe you could answer your own question, point to the PR and once it's merged update to reflect the new feature.