# Backbone Marionette: Collection not getting rendered

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

Would someone be able to tell me why this isn't rendering at all? I have been tirelessly trying to debug this for a long time now with no luck. It just wont render no matter what I do. On the success callback from the fetch function I log the data and it's there. However it just doesn't appear in the view.

```
import Bb from 'backbone';
import Mn from 'backbone.marionette';
import template from '../templates/LayoutTemplate.jst';
import ListasView from './ListasView.js';

const ListaCollection = Bb.Collection.extend({
  url: "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/lista/all",
  parse(data) {
    return data.lista;
  }
});

const listaCollection = new ListaCollection();

const LayoutView = Mn.View.extend({
  initialize() {
    listaCollection.fetch({
      reset: true,
      success(data) {
        console.log(data.toJSON());
      }
    });
  },
  collection: listaCollection,
  template: template,
  regions: {
    listasContainer: '#listas-container'
  },
  onRender() {
    this.showChildView('listasContainer', new ListasView({collection: listaCollection }));
  }
});

export default LayoutView;
```

And this is my template:

```
<% _.each(items, function(item) { %>
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col">
    <div class="demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
      <div class="mdl-card__title">
        <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text"><%= item.titulo %></h2>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
        <%= item.descricao %>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
        <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect show-modal">
          <i class="material-icons">arrow_forward</i>
        </button>
        <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
          <i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i>
        </button>
        <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
          <i class="material-icons">clear</i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% }) %>
```

Comment: It seems the collection has been rendered before the success callback. You can add on change event to render it again.

Comment: How does fetching the collection on initialize make sure that fetch is complete when the render occurs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render a Marionette region after model has been fetched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497763/render-a-marionette-region-after-model-has-been-fetched)

Comment: @TJ indeed fetching the collection on initialize through `this.collection =` fixed the problem! Thank you.